# spark-shell - How to avoid suppressing of elided stack trace (Exceptions)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-shell

I am trying to run on of my scala file from spark-shell. This file calling some other jar files which have already been loaded into spark-context

The problem is if something fails, it only prints the part of the stacktrace. Is there any way I can enable whole stacktrace?

```
myclassn: ClassifyFields : queryDb -> Problems extracting from DB
  at myclass.queryDb(ClassifyFields.java:231)
  at myclass.getColumnsWithKeys(ClassifyFields.java:258)
  ... 78 elided
```

Comment: Try doing a `try/catch` block and inside the `catch` block, write the stacktrace to a file..

Answer (score 5):

set the below value to zero.

`vals.isettings.maxPrintString=0`

like the example below

```
scala> :power
Power mode enabled. :phase is at typer.
import scala.tools.nsc._, intp.global._, definitions._
Try :help or completions for vals._ and power._

scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString
res0: Int = 800

scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString=0
vals.isettings.maxPrintString: Int = 0

scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString
res1: Int = 0
```

or after exception happened use the below

```
lastException.printStackTrace
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this from inside a Jupyter Notebook with Spark Scala code?

Comment: Proposed solution doesn't help :(

Comment: its doest not help, still see the same error stack trace